# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS shutting down randomly

Tags: shutdown, 22.04, hardware, crash, overheating

Laptop shuts down suddenly. Initially it happened when the laptop was not being used but recently it started happening even when I am using it. My laptop is quite old. I tried looking in kern.log and syslog. I tried looking if it was an overheating issue but was not able to confirm it.

kern.log

```
Aug 24 21:52:49 machineName kernel: [   51.477837] wlp2s0: authenticate with 64:70:02:4d:b1:8a
Aug 24 21:52:49 machineName kernel: [   51.492842] wlp2s0: send auth to 64:70:02:4d:b1:8a (try 1/3)
Aug 24 21:52:49 machineName kernel: [   51.495756] wlp2s0: authenticated
Aug 24 21:52:49 machineName kernel: [   51.496039] ath9k 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: disabling HT/VHT/HE as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
Aug 24 21:52:49 machineName kernel: [   51.496723] wlp2s0: associate with 64:70:02:4d:b1:8a (try 1/3)
Aug 24 21:52:49 machineName kernel: [   51.499688] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 64:70:02:4d:b1:8a (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=3)
Aug 24 21:52:49 machineName kernel: [   51.499870] wlp2s0: associated
Aug 24 21:52:49 machineName kernel: [   51.500058] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8164
Aug 24 21:52:49 machineName kernel: [   51.500064] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
Aug 24 21:52:49 machineName kernel: [   51.500068] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
Aug 24 21:52:49 machineName kernel: [   51.500070] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x5b
Aug 24 21:52:49 machineName kernel: [   51.500073] ath: Country alpha2 being used: IN
Aug 24 21:52:49 machineName kernel: [   51.500076] ath: Regpair used: 0x5b
Aug 24 21:52:49 machineName kernel: [   51.500079] ath: regdomain 0x8164 dynamically updated by country element
Aug 24 21:52:49 machineName kernel: [   51.692631] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
Aug 24 21:52:54 machineName kernel: [   56.587485] audit: type=1400 audit(1661358174.357:44): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=906 comm="cups-browsed" capability=23  capname="sys_nice"
Aug 24 21:53:16 machineName kernel: [   77.866519] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Aug 24 21:53:16 machineName kernel: [   78.523711] rfkill: input handler disabled
Aug 24 21:53:28 machineName kernel: [   90.287348] rfkill: input handler enabled
Aug 24 21:53:29 machineName kernel: [   90.936387] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Aug 24 21:53:29 machineName kernel: [   90.936405] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Aug 24 21:53:29 machineName kernel: [   90.936416] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
Aug 24 21:53:32 machineName kernel: [   93.848190] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Aug 24 21:53:34 machineName kernel: [   96.114584] rfkill: input handler disabled
Aug 24 21:53:37 machineName kernel: [   98.954244] audit: type=1400 audit(1661358217.244:45): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=1664 comm="snap-confine" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
Aug 24 21:53:37 machineName kernel: [   98.954328] audit: type=1400 audit(1661358217.244:46): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=1664 comm="snap-confine" capability=38  capname="perfmon"
Aug 24 21:53:37 machineName kernel: [   99.564931] audit: type=1400 audit(1661358217.856:47): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=1664 comm="snap-confine" capability=4  capname="fsetid"
Aug 24 21:53:46 machineName kernel: [  107.768314] audit: type=1326 audit(1661358226.053:48): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=? pid=1664 comm="snap-store" exe="/snap/snap-store/558/usr/bin/snap-store" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=314 compat=0 ip=0x7fcd8ba4073d code=0x50000
Aug 24 21:53:51 machineName kernel: [  113.502400] Lockdown: fwupd: /dev/mem,kmem,port is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Aug 24 21:53:52 machineName kernel: [  114.092374] audit: type=1107 audit(1661358232.374:49): pid=625 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=? msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.11" pid=1664 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=655 peer_label="unconfined"
Aug 24 21:53:52 machineName kernel: [  114.092374]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Aug 24 21:53:52 machineName kernel: [  114.092413] audit: type=1420 audit(1661358232.374:50): subj_apparmor=unconfined
Aug 24 21:53:52 machineName kernel: [  114.093396] audit: type=1107 audit(1661358232.374:51): pid=625 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=? msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.11" pid=1664 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=655 peer_label="unconfined"
Aug 24 21:53:52 machineName kernel: [  114.093396]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Aug 24 21:53:52 machineName kernel: [  114.093425] audit: type=1420 audit(1661358232.374:52): subj_apparmor=unconfined
Aug 24 21:53:52 machineName kernel: [  114.629655] audit: type=1107 audit(1661358232.910:53): pid=625 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=? msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.11" pid=1664 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=655 peer_label="unconfined"
Aug 24 21:53:52 machineName kernel: [  114.629655]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Aug 24 21:53:52 machineName kernel: [  114.629677] audit: type=1420 audit(1661358232.910:54): subj_apparmor=unconfined
Aug 24 21:53:52 machineName kernel: [  114.630466] audit: type=1107 audit(1661358232.910:55): pid=625 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=? msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.11" pid=1664 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=655 peer_label="unconfined"
Aug 24 21:53:52 machineName kernel: [  114.630466]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Aug 24 21:53:52 machineName kernel: [  114.630484] audit: type=1420 audit(1661358232.910:56): subj_apparmor=unconfined
Aug 24 21:53:54 machineName kernel: [  115.783520] audit: type=1400 audit(1661358234.061:57): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/etc/PackageKit/Vendor.conf" pid=1664 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Aug 24 23:17:03 machineName kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x21, date = 2019-02-13
Aug 24 23:17:03 machineName kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.15.0-46-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-115) (gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #49-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 18:03:25 UTC 2022 (Ubuntu 5.15.0-46.49-generic 5.15.39)
Aug 24 23:17:03 machineName kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-46-generic root=UUID=f7bda376-e787-4301-b8c4-b9c3ee95befa ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

23:17:03 is when I started my laptop again.

syslog

```
Aug 24 22:06:46 machineName dbus-daemon[1252]: [session uid=1000 pid=1252] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Characters.BackgroundService'
Aug 24 22:06:47 machineName dbus-daemon[625]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.timedate1'
Aug 24 22:06:47 machineName systemd[1]: Started Time & Date Service.
Aug 24 22:06:47 machineName dbus-daemon[1252]: [session uid=1000 pid=1252] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Calendar'
Aug 24 22:07:06 machineName google-chrome.desktop[2392]: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
Aug 24 22:07:06 machineName systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Aug 24 22:07:07 machineName systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 24 22:07:07 machineName systemd[1]: Finished Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Aug 24 22:07:17 machineName systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 24 22:07:48 machineName wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-52 noise=-95 txrate=54000
Aug 24 22:11:23 machineName wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-81 noise=-95 txrate=54000
Aug 24 22:11:29 machineName wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-67 noise=-95 txrate=36000
Aug 24 22:11:32 machineName wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-76 noise=-95 txrate=48000
Aug 24 22:11:34 machineName wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-64 noise=-95 txrate=1000
Aug 24 22:11:35 machineName wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-58 noise=-95 txrate=1000
Aug 24 22:11:35 machineName wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-53 noise=-95 txrate=1000
Aug 24 22:11:45 machineName wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-51 noise=-95 txrate=48000
Aug 24 22:13:03 machineName wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-74 noise=-95 txrate=54000
Aug 24 22:13:07 machineName wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-62 noise=-95 txrate=48000
Aug 24 22:13:11 machineName wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-61 noise=-95 txrate=48000
Aug 24 22:13:14 machineName wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-56 noise=-95 txrate=48000
Aug 24 22:13:37 machineName wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-49 noise=-95 txrate=54000
Aug 24 22:17:01 machineName CRON[3180]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug 24 22:18:32 machineName wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-70 noise=-95 txrate=54000
Aug 24 22:18:35 machineName wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-56 noise=-95 txrate=1000
Aug 24 22:18:35 machineName wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-56 noise=-95 txrate=1000
Aug 24 22:18:35 machineName wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-55 noise=-95 txrate=54000
Aug 24 22:19:30 machineName wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-50 noise=-95 txrate=54000
Aug 24 23:17:03 machineName systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Aug 24 23:17:03 machineName systemd[1]: Finished Set the console keyboard layout.
```

Again 23:17:03 is when I started my laptop again.

I performed a fresh installation of Ubuntu but that did not help. This was not a problem earlier. I am not sure but it might be a result of an update.

My laptop specifications:

```
-Computer-
Samsung NP350V5C-A02AE
Processor        : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz
Memory           : 3906MB (1374MB used)
Machine Type     : Laptop
Operating System : Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

OpenGL Renderer  : (Unknown)
X11 Vendor       : The X.Org Foundation
-Audio Devices-
Audio Adapter       : HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
-Input Devices-
 Power Button
 Lid Switch
 Power Button
 AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
 SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
 HDA Intel PCH Mic
 HDA Intel PCH Headphone
 HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm:3
-SCSI Disks-
ATA Hitachi HTS54755

-Product-
Name        : 350V5C/350V5X/350V4C/350V4X/351V5C/351V5X/351V4C/351V4X/3540VC/3540VX/3440VC/3440VX
Family      : Eureka
Vendor      : SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD.
Version     : P07ABE.010.CP
-BIOS-
Date        : 01/29/2013
Vendor      : American Megatrends Inc.
Version     : P07ABE
-Board-
Name        : NP350V5C-A02AE
Vendor      : SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD. (SAMSUNG, www.samsung.com)
Version     : BOARD REVISION 00
Serial Number       : (Not available; Perhaps try running HardInfo as root.)
Asset Tag       : Base Board Asset Tag
-Chassis-
Vendor      : SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD. (SAMSUNG, www.samsung.com)
Type        : [9] Laptop
Version     : 0.1
```

I am new to linux and I am just not able to figure this out.
Please help!

EDIT
I read an answer for a similar problem and and used the command ```

```
sudo journalctl -b -1 -e
```

to see the end of previous boot log. I am not quite able to figure it out. I thought I will add it in case it helps.

Edit: I performed a reinstall of Ubuntu 22.04. These are the logs I got using journalctl -b -1 -e command. I have removed the logs I provided using the same command to stay within the character limit.

```
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Unmounted /boot/efi.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-B95C\x2d2>
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Stopped File System Check on /dev/disk/by->
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Removed slice Slice /system/systemd-fsck.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Stopped target Preparation for Local File >
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Deacti>
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Deactivated succ>
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Stopped Create System Users.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: swapfile.swap: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /swapfile.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Deactivated su>
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Syste>
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Reached target System Shutdown.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Reached target Late Shutdown Services.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: systemd-poweroff.service: Deactivated succ>
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Finished System Power Off.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Reached target System Power Off.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Shutting down.
Aug 27 21:54:38 machineName systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block dev>
Aug 27 21:54:38 machineName systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining proc>
Aug 27 21:54:38 machineName systemd-journald[277]: Journal stopped
lines 986-1008/1008 (END)
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Unmounted /boot/efi.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-B95C\x2d2B32.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Stopped File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/B95C-2B32.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Removed slice Slice /system/systemd-fsck.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Stopped target Preparation for Local File Systems.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Stopped Create System Users.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: swapfile.swap: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /swapfile.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Reached target System Shutdown.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Reached target Late Shutdown Services.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: systemd-poweroff.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Finished System Power Off.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Reached target System Power Off.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Shutting down.
Aug 27 21:54:38 machineName systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
Aug 27 21:54:38 machineName systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
Aug 27 21:54:38 machineName systemd-journald[277]: Journal stopped
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
lines 986-1008/1008 (END)
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Unmounted /boot/efi.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-B95C\x2d2B32.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Stopped File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/B95C-2B32.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Removed slice Slice /system/systemd-fsck.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Stopped target Preparation for Local File Systems.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Stopped Create System Users.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: swapfile.swap: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /swapfile.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Reached target System Shutdown.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Reached target Late Shutdown Services.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: systemd-poweroff.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Finished System Power Off.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Reached target System Power Off.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Shutting down.
Aug 27 21:54:38 machineName systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
Aug 27 21:54:38 machineName systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
Aug 27 21:54:38 machineName systemd-journald[277]: Journal stopped
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
lines 986-1008/1008 (END)
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Unmounted /boot/efi.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-B95C\x2d2B32.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Stopped File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/B95C-2B32.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Removed slice Slice /system/systemd-fsck.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Stopped target Preparation for Local File Systems.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Stopped Create System Users.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: swapfile.swap: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /swapfile.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Reached target System Shutdown.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Reached target Late Shutdown Services.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: systemd-poweroff.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Finished System Power Off.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Reached target System Power Off.
Aug 27 21:54:37 machineName systemd[1]: Shutting down.
Aug 27 21:54:38 machineName systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
Aug 27 21:54:38 machineName systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
Aug 27 21:54:38 machineName systemd-journald[277]: Journal stopped
~
~
~
```

Comment: stating the obvious, but are you sure the power button (physical one) is not faulty? (ie. to force shutdown you push on the button for few secs)

Comment: @MaximeLibs I just checked. The button seems fine. If the button was faulty, then the computer should have started on its own too but that's not the case. Moreover, the button has a proper springy effect to it. So, it's probably fine.

Comment: @MaximeLibs I just updated the question with previous boot log. I hope this might help in figuring out the problem.